# PHP MySQL DSN Connections - How to enable mysql://

Tags: mysql, dsn, mysql-proxy

How do I enable this type of command on a mysql server and what is it?

I see it client code:

```
//$dsn = "mysql://root@localhost/username";
//$dsn = "mysql://admin@999.69.205.174/pass";
```

Normally I would expect:

```
$con=mysql_connect($db,$dbuSER,$dbpass);
```

Comment: That looks similar to the DSN used in a PDO constructor, but I don't know what API uses that exact format.

Comment: Since you have access to the code that uses this, locate a connection call and post it.

Comment: It says it is using PEAR - PEAR DB driver - any idea?

Comment: Ok, the PEAR DB module is becoming less common. See the documentation at http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.database.db.intro-dsn.php

Comment: Why is it less common? Speed?

Comment: I would assume because PDO is a more officially supported extension.  I've not worked with PEAR::DB in a long time to know its current state.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> In PHP using the PEAR::DB package to open a connection without an
>   external DSN (a "DSN-less connection", i.e., using a Connection
>   String), the code might resemble the following:

```
require_once("DB.php");
//$dsn = "<driver>://<username>:<password>@<host>:<port>/<database>";
$dsn = "mysql://john:pass@localhost:port/my_db";
$db = DB::connect($dsn);
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Source_Name